# Youtube Thumbnail not pulling through correctly

Tags: channel-videos, video

We pull through youtube images using CE Image like this:   {exp:ce_img:pair src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{id}/0.jpg" width="333" height="192" quality="84" interlace="yes" crop="yes"}

This has worked in the past, but now no longer works. It just pulls through the grey youtube default image.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be a universal fix, but it looks like you might have the wrong URL (or more likely YouTube has changed it).  Just grabbed an image from YouTube site and the URL looked like this:

```
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{id}/0.jpg
```

i.e. the FQDN has changed from the one you are using in your code snip.

HTH.